# Positioning a div at bottom of another div without specified height

Tags: html

I Have this HTML

```
<div style="position: relative;">

<div style="top:0">

</div>

<div style='position: absolute; bottom:0; margin-bottom:0px;'>


</div>

</div>
```

This code is working absolutely fine for IE but on other browsers the two inner div are overlapping, I cannot give any specified height to the outer div.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need absolute positioning :

```
<div style="position: relative;">

    <div style="background:black;">
        test
    </div>

    <div style='background:red;'>
        test    
    </div>

</div>
```

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/BzTLK/).

Comment: I have used it here
http://www.spoiledagent.com/
the problem is that the height of the other pages are different and I want the side banners has to be aligned at the bottom
like this
http://www.spoiledagent.com/about.html

Comment: open these pages on IE and mozilla
http://www.spoiledagent.com/
http://www.spoiledagent.com/about.html
You will know what exactly I want